# Convert std::vector to std::string without \0

Tags: c++

I want to remove the vowels from a `std::string` with this code:

```
# include <string>
#include <vector>

bool IsVowel(char c) {
    return ((c == 'a') ||
        (c == 'A') ||
        (c == 'e') ||
        (c == 'E') ||
        (c == 'i') ||
        (c == 'I') ||
        (c == 'o') ||
        (c == 'O') ||
        (c == 'u') ||
        (c == 'U'));
}

std::string RemoveVowel(const std::string& str) {
    const size_t s = str.length();

    std::vector<char> inProgress(s);

    int index = 0;
    for (char c : str) {
        if (!IsVowel(c)) {
            inProgress[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
    }

    std::string sy(inProgress.begin(), inProgress.end());
    return sy;

}
```

But with this input:

```
"aaaaaa"
```

I get this output:

```
"\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

But I want to get this:

```
""
```

The problem is with `std::string sy(inProgress.begin(), inProgress.end());`. I don't know how to convert the `std::vector` to `std::string` without any `\0`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: fwiw, the canonical way to do this with c++20 is `std::erase_if(myString, isVowel);`. But then you no longer write the algorithm so the learning value is minimal. In real code that's what you would do, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `inProgress` always contains `str.length()` many elements. `index` tells you the actual number of vowels in there. `std::string` has [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that let you use that information to determine how much of `inProgress` to use in the initialization of `sy`.

So, you could do:

```cpp
std::string sy(inProgress.begin(), inProgress.begin() + index);
return sy;
```

This would construct `sy` using only the initial segment of `inProgress` that actually contains vowels.

Comment: Using index and then recreating an iterator from begin() is quite odd, why not just work with iterators to begin with?

Comment: You could replace `index` with an iterator and the code would look pretty similar. I wanted to propose a change that left as much of the asker's original code intact as possible. If I were writing this from scratch I'd probably do one of the `push_back`-style approaches the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 3):

[The answer by Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72241389/2752075) explains how to do what you want.

But there are easier ways:

C++20 or newer:

```
std::string RemoveVowel(std::string str)
{
    std::erase_if(str, IsVowel);
    return str;
}
```

C++17:

```
std::string RemoveVowel(std::string_view str)
{
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(str.size()); // Optional.
    std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), std::not_fn(IsVowel));
    return ret;
}
```

C++14 and earlier:

```
std::string RemoveVowel(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(str.size()); // Optional.
    std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), [](char ch){return !IsVowel(ch);});
    return ret;
}
```

Even if you don't want to keep the custom loop, you should replace `std::vector` with a `std::string` to avoid the extra copy at the return.

Comment: Is string manipulation with changing sizes as fast as `std::vector` so that avoiding the extra copy would give a speedup?

Comment: @Sebastian I've added `reserve` calls, should be better now.

Comment: `std::string::reserve()` does not take another `std::string` as input. Did you mean to use `ret.reserve(str.size())` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could not pass in an initial size for your vector and use `push_back`:

```
std::string RemoveVowel(const std::string& str) {
  std::vector<char> in_progress;
  in_progress.reserve(str.size());
  for (const char& c : str) {
    if (!IsVowel(c)) {
      in_progress.push_back(c);
    }
  }
  std::string sy(in_progress.begin(), in_progress.end());
  return sy;
}
```

Or alternatively use a [`stringstream`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) instead:

```
std::string RemoveVowel(const std::string& str) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  for (const char& c : str) {
    if (!IsVowel(c)) {
      ss << c;
    }
  }
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: In the first case, it makes sense to call `vector::reserve()` (not `resize()`) before entering the loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would you not be unnecessarily reserving extra space in a case like `"aaaaaaa"` though?

Comment: Yes, but since the function doesn't know what input it is receiving, it might end up needing the full length if there are no  vowels at all. If you have any idea of the max length you might need, it is usually better to overallocate one time before the loop than to potentially reallocate over and over inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use [std::vector::push_back(value)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to insert new valid characters into your vector, rather than setting null values.

```cpp
for (char c : str) {
    if (!IsVowel(c)) {
        inProgress.push_back(c);
    }
}
std::string sy(inProgress.begin(), inProgress.end());
return sy;
```

Alternatively, can't you simply just [append](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) to an output string?

```cpp
std::string sy = "";
for (char c : str) {
    if (!IsVowel(c)) {
        sy += c;
    }
}
return sy;
```

Comment: In the first case, it makes sense to call `vector::reserve()` before entering the loop. In the second case, `string::reserve()` instead.